# Interaction betewen Makefile, the Java RMI module and Java packages

Tags: java, eclipse, makefile, rmi

To start, this project was developed in Eclipse and then all the source files were moved onto a Unix system to be tested. There are four different stages to my problem.

1. All files are in the default package : Project runs
2. Files are seperated into packages : Project no longer runs
3. Files are returned to the default package : Project still doesn't run
4. File contents are copied into another project : Project run

---

So, in the first stage we have 6 files, all in the default package. They are:

- Main.java (This chooses which type of RMI object to make and execute ie. Server/Client)
- RMIFunction.java {implements MapperInterface}
- RemoteInterface.java {implemets Remote}
- ConnectionInterface.java (This is to allow polymorphism in Main)
- RMIClient.java {implements ConnectionInterface}
- RMIServer.java {implements ConnectionInterface}

At this stage of my project everything runs fine, and all RMI Functions work.

---

In the second stage of my project, I decided to organize my files into packages.

- Application: Main.java
- Objects: Everything else
- Makefile: executes javac package/file.java for all files

At this point, my program has stopped working and I spend a good three hours researching my problem on Google (a good portion of that time on here). The errors might have something to do with the makefile changing the compiled files in some way that I don't know of(PS. I know practically nothing of makefiles, I took the one I used off the internet to compile all of my java files). I got a Connection error and I fooled around with rmiregistry calls(none of these worked, since the port was supposedly already being used by an unnamed program...)

---

My next stage was out of frustration, where I just put everything back into default package. I was hoping that everything would go back to the way it was. Lo and behold, it was still broken, but this time I had a different error:

UnmarshalException: ... nested exception; ClassNotFoundException

So, here I thought that the RMIFunctions_stub was not being found by my Main file, where the exception was being thrown. I did a lot of research into classpaths, which came up dry. I was particularly confused because I could see the file that was not found in the same directory as Main.

---

So, the fourth stage that I was reduced to was to make a whole new project, copy and paste all the contents of the 6 original files into new files(all named the same) and now it magically works.

If anyone can share some insight on how this problem happened/was resolved that would be fabulous. My intuition now is that there's some metadata stored somewhere in eclipse when you make a package, and that's what messed up the files in stage 3.

PS. If someone wants to see some actual code where my explanation is lacking, I'll put it up. I just didn't want to throw up 7 different files and overwhelm people trying to figure out the problem.

EDIT 02/08/2015 -

@immibis: stopped working was explained in the short explanations of the different stages, that is which errors were thrown and such.

@EJP: thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Define "stopped working".

Comment: Probably you didn't redeploy correctly, or possibly you didn't restart the Registry every time you changed the package structure. Moral of the story is not to fiddle around with package structures, and never to use the default package.